# Mapping values to integers

Tags: java, math

I'm really tired so this may be a stupid question and I'm just not thinking straight. But I'm trying to basically make it so that I can map

```
1 => 0
2 => 1
4 => 2
8 => 3
```

The context for this is that I have an array of stuff. Then I pass in a value, if the value's number is 1, I want to access the array offset by 0, if the value has a width of 2, offset by 1, if the value is 4, offset by 2, etc.

Is there some mathematical way I can do this nice and concisely? I figured a HashMap or something would be a bit overkill, and I'm sure there's a better way than a lookup in an array of 8 values.

Comment: What is the logic behind the mapping, if there is any?

Comment: (Slight edit in my mapping) So 1, 2, 4, 8 are sizes of types in bytes (byte, short, int, long). I'm storing instructions in an enumerator and I want to get say movb its MOV + 0, movs is MOV + 1. To make things nicer I can do MOV + get_width(type) where get_width will handle the mapping.

Comment: Why not use `sizeof()` ?

Comment: @MBo There isn't sizeof in Java :-) Plus that wouldn't work in my context since I'm not getting the size of actual values - it's for a compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and mathematical way to map the integers in the given pattern would be
`x => log2(x)` *if* the pattern continues as `16 => 4`, `32 => 5`, `64 => 6` and so on.

Most languages have a method to compute the logarithm of a number in the standard library. If that method computes the logarithm in a base other than 2, you can create a helper method that computes the log to the base 2 instead.

```
float log2(float x) {
    const float logOf2 = log(2);
    return log(x) / logOf2; // log() is your standard library log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the switch loop.

switch(value){
    case 1: return 1;
     break;
    case 2: return 2;
     break;
    case 4: return 3;
     break;
    case 8: return 4;
     break;
    default: return 0;
}

Comment: Aw I was hoping there would be some fancy math I could do with operations like % or + or - or something

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can add condition to throw exception if the array has wrong data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] vals = new int[]{1,2,4,8};
            for(int i : vals){
                System.out.println(getResult(i));
            }
        }

    private static int getResult(int element){
        int i = -1;
        int temp = 2;
        while(true){
            i++;
            int result = (int) Math.pow(temp,i);
            if(result == element){
                return i+1;
            }
        }


    }
```